# Trying to define an integer in C++ following these characteristics

Tags: c++

I need create an integer, lets call it X, where X is the amount needed to subtract from another integer, lets call that Y, to make Y the closest power of 2 + 1, where in X can not be greater than half of Y, and assuming that Y is not already a power of 2 + 1. For example if Y is 19, and I want it to be the closest power of 2 + 1 which would be 17, so X would need to be 2. I'm having a really hard time trying to figure this out. Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: This sounds more like a simple algebra problem. Do you mean that you have an assignment to write a computer program to solve this problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just can't figure out how to go about creating X based off Y :/ I've been staring at this problem for like an hour and my brain just doesn't want to work.

Comment: Well, can you figure out how you'd do it by hand, without writing a program? For instance, how did you solve the given example (where Y is 19)? If you can figure out how to describe the process to solve it by hand very precisely, that'll often put you on a good start to write code to do it.

Comment: Well I can do it if I don't need to write the code. The problem is that I don't really get how to create X in C++ to be 2 in the example of 19. Like I have the included library math.h to do logarithms and I know the syntax for all the things I need to do I just can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Right: what I mean is that if you can write down the process in English, in very small simple steps, it may show you what you need to do to write code. So, since you mentioned logarithms, maybe the first step is "let log_y be the log base 2 of Y." Then once you have log_y, what do you do next? And so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
Let 'n' = number of bits in binary representation of Y
X = Y - (2 pow (n-1) + 1);

ex: Y = 19 ( 5 bits)
n = 5.
X = 19 - (2 pow 4 + 1) = 19 - 17 = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int y = 63;
   int minx = log2(y);
   int x = y - (pow(2,minx) + 1);
   if (x > y / 2) 
   {
       x = y / 2;
   }
   cout << x << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

We can take advantage of the property that a power of 2 has exactly one bit set to 1: only a power of 2 (and zero) will return zero when bitwise ANDed with itself minus 1.

```
int ispow2plus1(int n)
{
    int pow2 = n - 1;
    return pow2 != 0 && (pow2 & (pow2 - 1)) == 0;
}
```

Consider 33.  `pow2` is then 32, which is not zero, and `pow2 & (pow2 - 1)` equals `32 & 31` - in binary, `100000 & 011111`, which is zero.

**EDIT**: somewhat under-scoped question based on misunderstanding in off-site chat.  You'll also need to find the most significant 1 bit in case what you have is not in fact a power of 2 plus 1.  I've gone out of my way here to avoid the use of floating-point math, thus the loop to remove 1 bits other than the most significant from pow2.

```
int pow2plus1excess(int n)
{
    int pow2 = n - 1;
    for (int temp = pow2; temp > 0; temp &= temp - 1) pow2 = temp;
    return (n - 1) & ~pow2;
}
```

This returns 0 if the number is a power of 2 plus 1, otherwise the excess beyond that point.  1, 2, 3, 9, and 33 all result in 0 returns, while 16 results in a return of 7.